# znapzend cannot receive new filesystem stream: dataset is busy

Tags: znapzend

have 2 test system running last Nexenta 4.0.3-FP4community .Master and  slave ,

mbuffer installed on both,ssh trust is ok between hosts

when running znapzend on master replication snapshot did not ship to slave system,here my znapzend znapzend debug log:

could you please somebody explain where is problem?

```
./znapzend --debug --runonce=oztssdpool/VMS
[Mon Jun  1 10:39:22 2015] [info] refreshing backup plans...
[Mon Jun  1 10:39:23 2015] [info] found a valid backup plan for oztssdpool/VMS...
[Mon Jun  1 10:39:23 2015] [debug] snapshot worker for oztssdpool/VMS spawned (28160)
[Mon Jun  1 10:39:23 2015] [info] creating recursive snapshot on oztssdpool/VMS
# zfs snapshot -r oztssdpool/VMS@2015-06-01-103923
[Mon Jun  1 10:39:23 2015] [debug] snapshot worker for oztssdpool/VMS done (28160)
[Mon Jun  1 10:39:23 2015] [debug] send/receive worker for oztssdpool/VMS spawned (28163)
[Mon Jun  1 10:39:23 2015] [info] starting work on backupSet oztssdpool/VMS
# zfs list -H -r -o name oztssdpool/VMS
[Mon Jun  1 10:39:23 2015] [debug] sending snapshots from oztssdpool/VMS to root@ozteksas1:oztsas1pool/VMS
# zfs list -H -o name -t snapshot -s creation -d 1 oztssdpool/VMS
# ssh -o Compression=yes -o CompressionLevel=1 -o Cipher=arcfour -o batchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=30 root@ozteksas1 zfs list -H -o name -t snapshot -s creation -d 1 oztsas1pool/VMS
# ssh -o Compression=yes -o CompressionLevel=1 -o Cipher=arcfour -o batchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=30 root@ozteksas1 zfs list -H -o name -t snapshot -s creation -d 1 oztsas1pool/VMS
[Mon Jun  1 10:39:24 2015] [debug] receive process on ozteksas1 spawned (28169)
# zfs send oztssdpool/VMS@2015-06-01-103923|/opt/csw/bin/mbuffer -q -s 128k -W 60 -m 256M -O 'ozteksas1:31338'
# ssh -o Compression=yes -o CompressionLevel=1 -o Cipher=arcfour -o batchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=30 root@ozteksas1 '/opt/csw/bin/mbuffer -q -s 128k -W 60 -m 256M -4 -I 31338|zfs recv -F oztsas1pool/VMS'
***cannot receive new filesystem stream: dataset is busy
[Mon Jun  1 10:39:28 2015] [debug] receive process on ozteksas1 done (28169)
Mojo::Reactor::Poll: Read failed: Event "close" failed:  at /opt/znapzend/bin/../lib/ZnapZend/ZFS.pm line 380.***
# ssh -o Compression=yes -o CompressionLevel=1 -o Cipher=arcfour -o batchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=30 root@ozteksas1 zfs list -H -o name -t snapshot -s creation -d 1 oztsas1pool/VMS
[Mon Jun  1 10:39:29 2015] [debug] cleaning up snapshots on root@ozteksas1:oztsas1pool/VMS
# zfs list -H -o name -t snapshot -s creation -d 1 oztssdpool/VMS
[Mon Jun  1 10:39:29 2015] [debug] cleaning up snapshots on oztssdpool/VMS
[Mon Jun  1 10:39:29 2015] [info] done with backupset oztssdpool/VMS in 6 seconds
[Mon Jun  1 10:39:29 2015] [debug] send/receive worker for oztssdpool/VMS done (28163)
```

Comment: that dataset error seems odd ... does send/recv with the command line above work when you execute it by hand ?

Comment: master system                                                                                       zfs send oztssdpool/FILES@2015-06-01-140928|/opt/csw/bin/mbuffer -q -s 128k -W 60 -m 256M -O 'ozteksas1:31338'                                            slave system                                                                      /opt/csw/bin/mbuffer -q -s 128k -W 60 -m 256M -4 -I 31338|zfs recv -F oztsas1pool/FILES
cannot receive new filesystem stream: dataset is busy                                         did you mean like this?

Comment: yes Tobi same result when I tried by hand ,but it works with ssh by hand when I remove destination zvol from slave system

Answer (score 2):

I found answer myself,
when destitaion zvol shared(lun mapping) this error occurs,

after unsharing destination zvol,znapzend working since yesterday.

Comment: Same here, I was exporting the `zvol` with iSCSI and even though it wasn't being used during the send/recv. In my case (using FreeNAS) I temporarily removed the iSCSI Extent and it worked like a charm.